# Incorrect button location in dumpsys activity on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, dumpsys

1. On a new Virtual Device (Pixel 4, api version 30, Android 11) I open Chrome, and click "Accept & Continue" on the Welcome to Chrome Screen.
2. At this point Chrome in is on "Turn on Sync" screen and there is a "No thanks" button on the screen.
3. Then I switch to the terminal on my mac and run
   `adb shell dumpsys activity top`

Result contains following lines:

```
org.chromium.chrome.browser.signin.AccountSigninView{1080,0-2160,1977}
  android.widget.LinearLayout{0,1790-1080,1977 #7f0b009c app:id/button_bar}
     org.chromium.ui.widget.ButtonCompat{44,44-299,143 #7f0b02d1 app:id/negative_button}
```

`AccountSigninView` has coordinates **1080,0-2160,1977** that are outside of the screen, but the button is visible on the screen.
This behaviour is not reproduced on my phone.

Questions:

1. How can I understand that this button is actually visible and not outside of the screen?
2. How can adjust emulator so that it has the same behaviour as my regular phone?

### Update 1:

I tried running `adb shell uiautomator dump` and although there are no controls outside of screen bounds, the coordinates of button are zero.

```
<node
  resource-indroid.chrome:id/negative_button"
  ...
  bounds="[0,0][0,0]"/>
```

Comment: How about the other buttons/views? Anything else with size/coordinates of zero?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how to parse the output of `dumpsys acticity top`, but the 1080 and 2160 are the upper y and lower y coordinates of the layout. As to the other 2 numbers - I don't know how to parse them.
If you want to get the bounds of any view, you better use the `uiautomator dump` command. It outputs an xml file, where you can find the bounds of any view in the screen.

Comment: Thank you, i will have a look into uiautomator.
1080 - is the width of the screen. 1080,0 is the top right point of the screen and the first value in this pair is X coordinate

Comment: 1080,0-2160,1977 means that the view starts in the top right corner of the screen and continues to the right

Answer (score 1):

You can try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which uses `uiautomator` or other backends if available and also can do some adjustments to the coordinates, for example running

```
dump --bounds
```

in a similar situations (Chrome has already been setup), gives

```
...
android.widget.Button com.android.chrome:id/signin_promo_choose_account_button Choose another account ((143, 1900), (937, 2032))
...
```

so if you intention is to click the button, using AndroidViewClient you can simply do

```
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Choose another account').touch()
```